# Simplest method to call-forward in sequence until someone answers, then take a message

Tags: twilio, twilio-twiml

Without a server, what's the best way to (receiving a call), forward to the first number, timeout if not answered in ~15 seconds, then try another. After a few (no more numbers), take a message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

The simplest way is to use the [Find Me Twimlet](https://www.twilio.com/labs/twimlets/findme).

If you want more control over the actual code, you could use the [Twilio Functions Hunt template](https://github.com/twilio-labs/function-templates/tree/main/hunt) which can be deployed to [Twilio Functions](https://www.twilio.com/docs/runtime/functions), so you don't need your own server.

Comment: This worked. As I get in very rarely, I had to find 'Flow' in the Studio (for future readers). The only way to get the call->call->voicemail to work was to fill in the FailUrl with yet another Twimlet from the same site (voicemail) where it then transcribes and emails too. Awesome solution - thanks.